How to Prevent Character Controller Descent at Platform Edges When Using a Capsule Collider
CONTEXT: I am implementing a basic 3D character controller from scratch in Unity. For collisions, I do a capsule cast in the direction of the player velocity and use the collide and slide algorithm to adjust the velocity to not go through the ground or walls, this is working as I'd expect. I'm using the capsule collider since the rounded bottom allows for smooth movement over ground obstacles.
ISSUE: On the edge of platforms or cliffs, before falling off, the character descends slightly due to the rounded bottom. In most games I've played, the character walks right to the edge and does not descend right until they fall off the edge. The image at the bottom illustrates this descent before falling in 2D.
What are some potential alternative approaches to maintain smooth control over uneven ground but avoid weird behavior at the edges of platforms and cliffs?

